# devenv Start Debugging is greyed out, and run says Attach

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

So I use 4coder, which doesn't come with its own debugger. I compile via a batch file and
I'm trying to use devenv which visual studio provides, to debug. However, like the title says, `Start Debugging` is greyed out, and run says `Attach`. I'm following the Handmade Hero tutorial and he's able to debug just fine.

I'm guessing it has no way of knowing I'm using C++, so how do I tell it?

These aren't the problem, but I thought I'd at least give some context on how I'm calling it.
Here's my batch files:

d:\Handmade\misc\env.bat

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=x64 -host_arch=x64 -no_logo
set path=d:\Handmade\misc;%path%
```

d:\Handmade\misc\debug.bat

```
@echo off
devenv d:\Handmade\code\%1%
```

**CommandLine**

```
D:\>debug main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found it out myself. If I target the built exe, and pass the project folder as the second parameter, it works.

```
@echo off
devenv d:\Handmade\build\main.exe d:\Handmade\code\%1%
```